# Squeel working in Rails Console but not in Controller. Error: undefined method `method' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I'm using Squeel, and I have an odd problem. The following line runs just fine in Rails Console, but gives an error when run in the model's controller!

`Issue.joins{property.users}.where{property.users.id == 1}`

Issue belongs_to Property, and Property has_and_belongs_to_many Users. I'm trying to load all the issues associated with the user_id == 1.

I get the error: "*undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass*" when I run the line in the IssuesController, but it works in Rails Console. What's wrong?

P.S. I'm running Rails 4.0.3, Ruby 2.0.0, and Squeel 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
my_properties = Property.where{user_id == 1}.select{issue_id}
Issue.where{id.in(my_properties)}
```